# List All Executables in any of your environment PATHs using Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, command-prompt

Is there a way to list all executables available with your current PATH (environment variable) setting with a batch file?

I've been trying for a while and I can't seem to find a way (i ain't no batch intellectual).

Please help if you can even a link to an article can be useful.
Thank you!

Comment: split on path separator and iterate doing `dir %path_segment%\*.exe`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

surprisingly simple:

```
for %a in (%pathext%) do where *%a
```

the `%pathext%` lists all defined file extension that are executable (.exe, .bat, ...) and `where` lists all findings within the `%path%`

Note: this is command line syntax. For use in a batch file, use `%%a` instead of `%a`

Comment: Great one! Note: this also returns all executables in the current working directory...

Comment: @aschipfl, I suppose a random directory could be made first and do a CD to that directory.  Or maybe set the `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` system variable.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the already provided answer, and as a result of @aschipfl's comment, the following should use only the locations defined in the `%Path%` environment variable, and not include the current directory, *(unless that itself was in `%Path%`)*.

From the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In (%PathExt%) Do @Where $Path:*%A 2>Nul
```

And from a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In (%PathExt%) Do @Where $Path:*%%A 2>Nul
```

---

Obviously if you were only looking for `.exe` files as opposed to executables it would be much simpler:

```bat
Where $Path:*.exe 2>Nul
```

Comment: This one is even better than the accepted answer, because it emits a continuous list without breaks. Combined with `| find ` or `| findstr` it's marvellous!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to solely use `CMD`'s native facilities without relying on external executables, which can also be used on older versions of windows like Windows XP where `Where.exe` is not available.

In a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%D in ("%PATH:;=";"%") do (
    for /F "eol=* delims=" %%F in ('cd /d "%%~D" 2^>nul ^&^& dir /b/a-d %PATHEXT:.=*.% 2^>nul') do (
        for %%F in ("%%~D\%%F") do echo %%~fF
    )
)
```

Technically, The innermost `FOR` is not vital, It is just to handle the anomalies that sometimes could be seen in the `PATH` environment variable, like where some path elements have trailing backslash, to output file paths in the standard format.

Because of it's length, Its not suited well for using at Command Prompt, however with my tests and to my sureprise, it is faster than the equivalent solution with `Where`.

One-liner for use at Command Prompt (For the sake of completeness):

```
@for %D in ("%PATH:;=";"%") do @for /F "eol=* delims=" %F in ('cd /d "%~D" 2^>nul ^&^& dir /b/a-d %PATHEXT:.=*.% 2^>nul') do @for %F in ("%~D\%F") do @echo %~fF
```